# how often does the GPS return the speed information

Tags: performance, gps

I am working on a mobile APP that can detect activity speed through Google map API.

I wonder how often does the GPS return the speed information? I would like to know the specific time interval like every 0.25 second or every 0.1 second?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The speed is returned with every location fix.
A Gps receiver can be set for which intervall to use.
In the past the minimum interval was 1s, now some receiver provide
0,5s.
Some specialized receiver even 0.1s
On Smartphones the minimum intervall is 1 per second.

If your application has direct access to the receiver you have to read the specification of the GPS chip manufacturer which intervall you can use.